# Why is event.defaultPrevented undefined?

Tags: javascript

As per the MDN docs, a click event should have a property called `preventedDefault`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented

However, in my code, `defaultPrevented` is undefined (Chrome and Safari). Instead  there is another property called: `isDefaultPrevented` which seems to do the trick, however, this does not work in iOS Safari.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.isDefaultPrevented; // returns true in Chrome (if event.preventDefault() was called)
    event.defaultPrevented; // the "correct" way to do it as per MDN docs, however, it doesn't work in Chrome nor iOS.
});
```

Comment: Your code says `preventedDefault`, not `defaultPrevented`. There's no such thing as `preventedDefault`.

Comment: That is also a jQuery event object which is normalized.

Comment: @epascarello theres no difference, just because it's jQuery

Comment: @FooBar There are some differences in the event object. This property may not be altered, but other are. There is an orginalEvent which has the unaltered version.

Comment: @FooBar Happy to undo the downvote and remove the close vote now that you have corrected the mistake. It's your responsibility to, to the extent possible, provide code that reproduces the issue (providing a Stack Snippet would be extra nice). The fact that you had two words reversed shows that you weren't paying attention.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to do it, if you're using jQuery.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
     event.originalEvent.defaultPrevented; // aparently jQuery will alter the event property, but it stores everything in 'originalEvent'
});
```